# Unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to gather data from jenkins using groovy script and getting an error:

> unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder

Below is the code:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
use ( TimeCategory ) {
    // e.g. find jobs not run in last 1 year
    sometimeago = (new Date() - 1.year)
}

jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()
lastabort = null
jobs.each { j ->
    if (j instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) { return }

    numbuilds = j.builds.size()

    if (numbuilds == 0) {
        println 'JOB: ' + j.fullName
        println '  -> no build'
        return
    }

    lastbuild = j.builds[numbuilds - 1]
    if (lastbuild.timestamp.getTime() < sometimeago) {
        println 'JOB: ' + j.fullName
        println '  -> lastbuild: ' + lastbuild.displayName + ' = ' + lastbuild.result + ', time: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2
    }
}
```

The error is:

> rg.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsExceptio‌​n:
>   startup failed: Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class
>   com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder @ line 12, column 20. if (j
>   instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) { return } ^ 1
>   error at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(Erro‌​rCollector.java:302)

Comment: The error is rg.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder 
 @ line 12, column 20.
     if (j instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) { return }
                      ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)

Answer (score 1):

I see [`Folder.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/Folder.java) in [`jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin).

That means you need to:

- check if you do have [JENKINS/CloudBees Folders Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) installed, or your groovy script would not be able to resolve that dependency.
- Add "`import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*`" to be sure the script is able to make the `instanceOf` work.

Answer (score 0):

When running groovy scripts that import libraries in Jenkins, check that your Jenkins build step is an "Execute *system* Groovy script", not a plain old "Execute Groovy script".

The 'system' scripts run on the existing JVM, as opposed to spawning a new one and therefore **losing access to** the shared **libraries** available to the original Jenkins JVM instance.

Groovy Script vs System Groovy Script - https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/