# Error cleanup script CloudBees Jenkins unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

My question is about a groovy script that fails. 
I tried to run it from a freestyle job with a Build Step "Execute system Groovy script" and 'Groovy command' where I have pasted the [script from this source](https://gist.github.com/EvilBeaver/35ebded526fb53ecb9716889c1de11df) and I also tried running the scripts directly from the script console.
(Another script I tried which gives a different error: [this one](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/CleanBuildHistory.groovy))

I found [this article already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459580/unable-to-resolve-class-com-cloudbees-hudson-plugins-folder-folder) here and some other ones, but it hasn't helped me out so far so I would like to run it by the community here.
I understand that there's likely more to it than described here, but I have hope.

I am admin of a couple of old (v1.580.13) Cloudbees Jenkins servers I need to support and can't yet decommission and I used to run a cleanup script which clears out workspaces on slaves.
Environment (masters and agents)

- OLD = RHEL 6.x physical - there the script worked
- NEW = CentOS 7.x VM - here it doesn't

For some reason that is beyond me it is not working on my new environment and produces an error that refers to the Folders plugin which I don't understand since the plugin is installed and was not changed as far as I know.

Both "[Folders Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin)" (4.7) and "[CloudBees Folders Plus Plugin](http://release-notes.cloudbees.com/product/Folders+Plus+Plugin)" (2.10) are installed and I can see the related files in:

```
$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-folder
$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/cloudbees-folder.jpi
../cache/war/WEB-INF/plugins/cloudbees-folder.hpi
```

[Groovy plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) v1.14 is also installed as is Groovy runtime (Groovy Version: 1.8.9 JVM: 1.8.0_191 Vendor: Oracle Corporation as OS package as well as having 'Groovy installations' in Jenkins configuration: Groovy 2.5.4 & 2.1.9 from http://groovy.codehaus.org - install automatically) for master and agents.

The exact error output in the console is:

```
    FATAL: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder 
 @ line 19, column 24.
   if(item instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder) {
                      ^

1 error

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder 
 @ line 19, column 24.
   if(item instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder) {
                      ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:861)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:550)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:499)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:723)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:680)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:666)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Help is greatly appreciated!